# Multi-peer connectivity without BrowserViewController UI

Tags: ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I am using Multi-peer connectivity framework and have tried Apple example it works fine, but I want to modify it and instead of using inbuilt browser view controller UI i want to do it with my own UI / code , is it possible to discover devices without the inbuilt UI ?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307961/connect-browser-advertiser-without-showing-alert-message-in-multipeer-connecti/21336757#21336757).  I think you'll find the answer there but the short of it is that it is possible.  Here is a [link to a post at NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/) that will walk you through the work too.

Comment: thanks for reply, the answer is one step ahead and gives exactly what i want