# Is it possible to connect to a Multipeer Connectivity session without an invitation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to create an app similar to FireChat where users are automatically connected to a Multipeer Connectivity session without sending or receiving invitations to connect.

All the tutorials i have seen make use of the MCBrowserViewController. It must be possible to join a session without having to select a peer to connect and send and accept a request to connect if Firechat soes it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-peer connectivity without BrowserViewController UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652797/multi-peer-connectivity-without-browserviewcontroller-ui)

Comment: have you found a stable solution? anything published in that regard?

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using an MCBroswerViewController, you can use MCNearbyServiceBrowser.
It will then call a delegate method:

```
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

Then you can automatically send an invitation with something like:

```
[browser invitePeer:peerID
            toSession:self.session
          withContext:nil
              timeout:10];
```

However, in doing this, I've ran into tons of other problems. So far it seems:

- If both devices send invitations and accept them, then they randomly disconnect very soon.
- If both devices are advertising and broadcasting at the same time, then they randomly disconnect.

I'm actually working on an open source library right now to try and do exactly what you're asking for: Connect devices without any invitations or browser necessary (no UI).

Here it is: https://github.com/plivesey/PLPartyTime

However, it is not working yet. I haven't fully solved both issues above, but if you want to check out the code and see what you can work out, go for it. Please let me know of any progress you make though. This framework is frustrating to deal with...

Comment: I found out eventually about MCNearbyServiceBrowser and created an implementation. I know about the problems when both send invitations and accept them so what i did was to give one peer priority over the other. The priority is defined by who has the earliest "open app" timestamp (who opened the app first) and who has already peers connected. I store this information in the DiscoveryInfo NSDictionary. :) The peer with priority gets to send the invitation while the other just waits.

Comment: Another way of doing this is just comparing the peerIDs. Whoever has a lower peerID gets priority.

Comment: @plivesey is method is the recommended best practise when developing for iOS 7. However from iOS 8 onwards, this should not cause any issues, as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1869/_index.html.